# Angular 7 : Get specific sub-object in Json request

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I would like to retrieve the list of these seances compared to the id of the movie.

For this, in my Api I have a request that allows me to retrieve the list of seances.

**JSON Request**

```
{
"seances": [{
  "id": 1,
  "date": "2019-02-25 14:36:54",
  "movie": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Stargate : La porte des étoiles",
    "date": "1994-10-27",
    "poster": "Contacté par l'armée américaine, le jeune égyptologue de génie, Daniel Jackson, résout en 1994 l'énigme du gigantesque anneau de pierre et d'acier découvert en 1928 sur le site de la grande pyramide de Gizeh. Cette mission va le projeter à des années-lumière de la Terre chez des extra-terrestres qui ont construit les Pyramides. Un nouveau monde s'ouvre alors ..."
  },
  "room": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Super salle",
    "blueprint": "un plan",
    "placenumber": 12,
    "techno": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "IMAX"
    }
  }
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "date": "2019-02-25 14:36:54",
  "movie": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Stargate : La porte des étoiles",
    "date": "1994-10-27",
    "poster": "Contacté par l'armée américaine, le jeune égyptologue de génie, Daniel Jackson, résout en 1994 l'énigme du gigantesque anneau de pierre et d'acier découvert en 1928 sur le site de la grande pyramide de Gizeh. Cette mission va le projeter à des années-lumière de la Terre chez des extra-terrestres qui ont construit les Pyramides. Un nouveau monde s'ouvre alors ..."
  },
  "room": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Super salle",
    "blueprint": "un plan",
    "placenumber": 12,
    "techno": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "IMAX"
    }
  }
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "date": "2019-02-25 14:36:54",
  "movie": {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Stargate : La porte des étoiles",
    "date": "1994-10-27",
    "poster": "Contacté par l'armée américaine, le jeune égyptologue de génie, Daniel Jackson, résout en 1994 l'énigme du gigantesque anneau de pierre et d'acier découvert en 1928 sur le site de la grande pyramide de Gizeh. Cette mission va le projeter à des années-lumière de la Terre chez des extra-terrestres qui ont construit les Pyramides. Un nouveau monde s'ouvre alors ..."
  },
  "room": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Super salle nul",
    "blueprint": "un plan",
    "placenumber": 12,
    "techno": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "IMAX"
    }
  }
}]
}
```

---

For example, I would like to get the list of seances for the movie with id = 1.

I have made this code for get a list of seances with specific id of movie in my component :

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
   this.sceanceService.list().pipe(
      map(model => {
         return model.filter(movies => movies.movie.filter(movieid => movieid.id === this.id));
      })
      ).subscribe(data => {
         this.sceance = data;
   });
}
```

The detail of this service SceanceService

```
export class SceanceService extends ApiService<number, Sceance> {
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      super(http, 'sceances');
   }
}
```

And the detail of this service Api Service

```
export class ApiService<I, T extends Resource<I>> {

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private endpoint: string
  ) { }
  list(): Observable<T[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<T[]>(`${API_BASE_URL}/${this.endpoint}`);
  }

  create(item: T): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpClient
      .post<T>(`${API_BASE_URL}/${this.endpoint}`, item);
  }

  update(item: T): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpClient
      .put<T>(`${API_BASE_URL}/${this.endpoint}/${item.id}`, item);
  }

  get(id: I): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpClient.get<T>(`${API_BASE_URL}/${this.endpoint}/${id}`);
  }

  delete(id: I) {
    return this.httpClient.delete(`${API_BASE_URL}/${this.endpoint}/${id}`);
  }
}
```

My models class

```
export class Sceance {
    id: number;
    date: Date;
    movie: Movie[] = [];
    room: Room[] = [];
}
export class Movie {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    date: Date;
    poster: string;
}
export class Room {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    blueprint: string;
    placeLenght: number;
    techno: Techno[] = [];
}
export class Techno {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

When I build my project, I get this callstack :

```
ERROR TypeError: movies.movie.filter is not a function
    at sceance-container.component.ts:25
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at MapSubscriber.project (sceance-container.component.ts:25)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:41)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:38)
    at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:84)
```

I don't understand why the browser does not get to the filter function, when it exists.

---

Do you have any idea where the problem might come from?

Do you know a better way to recover this type of information?

**EDIT**

Add Models class

Comment: The value `movies.movie` is an object. You can use filter only on arrays

Comment: Your response is just a list of Seances with no Movie information at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is incorrect, a `seances` has a `movie` and not a `movies` array and therefor `.filter` is indeed not a function. You need to correct your `Sceance` class like this. Same goes for the room, your JSON example only contains one room and not an array of rooms.

```
export class Sceance {
    id: number;
    date: Date;
    movie: Movie;
    room: Room;
}
```